# Python: Empty string evaluated to 'false'

Tags: python, radix

I maybe in a unique situation where evaluating empty string as true would save a couple lines of code. (I understand empty string evaluate to false. as the following)

```
''  and print ("empty string is true")
'0' and print ("non-empty string is true")

> non-empty string is true
```

Here is why:

This works ok. But check out the output.

```
 def baseN(num,b):
    return (num == 0) and "0" or 
           (baseN(num // b, b) + "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[num % b])

> baseN(32,16)
> 020
```

Changing the last result (at the end of the recursion) to print out empty string, gives me error.

```
 def baseN(num,b):
    return (num == 0) and "" or 
           ( baseN(num // b, b) + "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[num % b])

> baseN(32,16)
> File "<stdin>", line 2, in baseN
> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

This clearly wouldn't work because `(num==0) and "" (false)` would always evaluate to False -> leading to unterminated recursive call.

Is there a way to fix it using only the logical operations/expressions (without if/else statements) ?

The following will work. But it won't be using only logical operators.

```
def baseN(num,b):
    if (num==0):
       return ""
    else:
        return (baseN(num // b, b) 
               + "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[num % b])

baseN(32,16)
```

Comment: Why do you prefer using short-circuit evaluation rather than straightforward conditional logic?  Is this for an exercise?  I don't think "sav[ing] a couple lines of code" is worth the headache of preferring the former, plus the added confusion of whoever might have to read the code later.

Comment: The last example is the most readable by far; Why do you want to use the operators `and` and `or`, again?

Comment: They are used rampantly in code competition sites like codefight.com because they save a few characters of code. Which is also what I am trying to accomplish here. I know it is very silly :(

Comment: Why are you wasting your time on stupid "competitions" that promote badly written code ?

Comment: The 'challenge' part. I think it is the style and the rules of the competition (namely least characters == win) is the worst rule there is. I totally agree that it promote badly written code. But honestly, other parts of the competition (logic and speed, and even elegance and readability)  should really be gauged as well. If only machines (code-evaluation-scripts) can get smarter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python has a ternary operator:

```
def baseN(num,b):
    return baseN(num // b, b) + "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[num % b] if num else ""
```

Comment: This is definitely the least brain-hurting example which avoids usage of an "if-then" construct; Kudos for remembering the ternary operator.

Comment: Yeah, already considered that: but i am not looking for that tho. `def baseN(n,b):
    return "" if n==0 else(baseN(n//b,b)+"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[n%b])
`

Comment: "but i am not looking for that tho" => Why ? It's actually the pythonic way to write your function as a one-liner (whether i's pythonic to write it as a one-liner is another question, and as far as I'm concerned the answer is an obvious "no").

Comment: I will accept your answer. I should be more clear in the description on exactly what I look for. But, thanks. ^^

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly you want to evaluate an empty string as True.

In that case you can just negate an empty string and make it True instead of false:

```
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool(not "")
True
```

Comment: You're example results in TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'str' for OP's example.  He needs an empty string to be returned if num == 0, not a boolean which your example gives.

Comment: I understood from the question that the main focus is to evaluate a empty string as True. I sadly did not go further in evaluating his need, but from the rest of the code he posted your comment is valid.

Comment: Billy is correct. I needed the '' to return. I can't take boolean answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Python empty sequences are considered to be False, including strings. Lists however are considered True if they are non empty so your code above would work in the following case:

```
def baseN(num,b):
    return ''.join((num == 0) and [''] or 
        [( baseN(num // b, b) +  "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[num % b])])
```

Personally I believe this makes things a bit less readable and I would go with the if statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just aiming for shorter code you can omit the `else` part if you're returning anyway:

```
def baseN(num,b):
    if (num==0): return ""
    return (baseN(num // b, b) 
           + "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[num % b])
```

Personally, I find this more readable.

Comment: Please dont put the `return ""` on the same line as the test, it's considered very bad style.

Comment: I find that a ridiculous rule.

Comment: I absolutely don't care what *you* think about this convention. Wrt/ readability, putting the early return statement on it's own line makes for a much more readable code, and that's why cramming it on the same line is considered bad style.

Comment: With such a simple condition it's perfectly readable. With more complex code, I agree. In this case wasting vertical space will just reduce  higher level readability of the program. Not worth the trade-off in my opinion. (Also, please lay off the condescending tone)